# Angular two way data binding inside directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-services

I have a problem with understanding how two way data binding works inside directive. Seems it's working only one way cause when i update value by typing directly in input field model is not being updated even though the datasource is set with '='. When i click change item button model is also updated. Why typing inside input fields doesn't update the model?

Also if factories/services are singletons why i'am able to create new instances of Item  by clicking the button and each one of the holds separate value?

I wasn't sure if those two problems are related to each other or not that's why asking it this way. [PLUNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/7kG5KBTeRTTTKejpemk2?p=preview)

```
angular.module('singletonServicesTest', [])
    .controller('pageCtrl', function(Item) {
        vm = this;
        vm.items = [];

        vm.addItem = function() {
            console.log('changeItem');
            var item = new Item();
            vm.items.push(item);
        };

        vm.addItemWithContent = function() {
            var item = new Item('some content');
            vm.items.push(item);
        };

        vm.changeItem = function() {
            console.log('change');
            vm.items[0].content = Math.random();
        };
    })
    .factory('Item', function() {
        function Item(data) {
            if (data) {
                this.content = data;
            }
        }

        Item.prototype.content = '';
        return Item;
    })
    .directive('itemDirective', function() {
        return {
            scope: {
                datasource: '='
            },
            template: '<div><input value="{{datasource.content}}" /></div>'
        }
    });

<body ng-app="singletonServicesTest" ng-controller="pageCtrl as page">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <button ng-click="page.addItem()">Add item</button>
    <button ng-click="page.addItemWithContent()">Add item with content</button>
    <button ng-click="page.changeItem()">change item</button>

    <div ng-repeat="item in page.items">
        <item-directive datasource="item"></item-directive>
    </div>
    {{page.items}}
</body>
```

Comment: the problem is in your template;  `value` isn't angular aware, and doesn't create a binding.  use `ng-model` instead.

Comment: and to your question about factories;  it's not the *result* of the factory function that is a singleton, it's the *function itself*.  the function will still be executed every call, but you won't get multiple copies of the function in memory. or, if the factory were to be attached to objects and then changed, it would be changed on every object it is attached to.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/dIX4JTsjkm9B3UnhWkuO

Comment: Ok, the problem with binding is clear. So it is perfectly safe to use factories/services this way to create multiple domain objects, cause each one of them will contain separate data, will be separate instance, but the function will be loaded only once into memory?

Comment: you keep trying to use factory and service interchangeably, but the only thing they have in common is that they both are providers.  This particular factory is a function that returns a unique item each time it is called;  a service would normally hold a single instance of an object and return that single instance each time.